# Can I find detailed flight parameters of some space mission(s)?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, scientific-data

I'm studying dynamic models and creating a mathematical model for spaceflight simulation. I need to check the correctness of my model.

Can I find detailed parameters of a spaceflight (say, position and speed diagrams in time) somewhere on the Internet in order to simulate it and compare the results? Say, some of the Apollo flights to the Moon.

Answer (score 8):

The ["Flight Evaluation Reports"](http://www.google.com/search?q=saturn%20v%20launch%20vehicle%20flight%20evaluation%20report%20site:nasa.gov) from the Apollo missions have a number of data plots and tables that may help you.

Bob Braeunig developed a simulation that matched the Apollo 11 flight report rather well, which you may want to refer to; unfortunately he seems to have taken it down but [it's available on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171102195112/http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm).

You can probably find similar data for other NASA missions on ntrs.nasa.gov with the right google search terms. Commercial and former-USSR launches tend to be a little less free with their data.

Comment: thx! it's such a pity that so much web pages disappear for various reasons; that's why I'm advocating the use of revision control systems to share websites (including their code) so that collaboration and preservation improves. in the case of Robert A. Braeunig, publishing a site as a Git repository would increase preservation dramatically.
It's also interesting to notice that he writes "... original simulation was written in a now obsolete programming language, ...give it another try. " So from an archival point of view it is so interesting to see what the first version looked like...

Comment: Braeunig’s site is otherwise still up, so one presumes he had a particular reason for taking down his Saturn launch sim page.